# Why are my tables not showing up in SQL Server Management Studio's intellisense?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't pull up my tables so I can use them in my stored procedure. Any reason why they aren't showing?

[image]

Comment: Pro Tip:  When you have the only question with a given tag (as shown by the number next to tag name when typing it in), it's probably not a good choice.  This was the ONLY question on the site with the 'mssql' tag.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Have you just created them? Intellisense data used by it is cached. Try to refresh it

> Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local
>   Cache

Comment: DARN! Beat me by **8 seconds** !!

Comment: CONTROL + SHIFT + R is the shortcut for that, nice to add this too.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer!

Answer (score 12):

Have you done a "Edit > Intellisense > Refresh local cache" lately??

Keyboard shortcut:  Ctrl + Shift + R

After adding lots of tables, intellisense gets out of sync at times...

Marc

Comment: Forget lots of tables. I just added a single UDF and it was out of synch immediately. Is there some kind of setting to tell it to automatically refresh when you create objects?

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the 'Tables' and select 'Refresh'

Answer (score 1):

For those using SQL Server Management Studio 2016 you simply need to hit 'F5' or go to 'View > Refresh' and your recently added tables should appear.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the above answer is not working for you, then

Expand your database >> Security >> Users >> double click user.

Under 'Select a page' >> Membership >> Make sure db

Answer (score 1):

Okay first try to refresh tables if that doesn't word then just above the object explorer there is an drop down box it should have name of the database you have given earlier.. sometimes it will have default value master so check it and if its master there click on drop down box and select the name of database and then click excute and refresh table now the table should appear..

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the "Tables" in your current database. It works.
Right Click on "Tables" and click on "Refresh"

Comment: Welcome @A_N to Stackoverflow. This question already has answers and was asked almost 12 years ago. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)