# How to make intellisense in SQL Server Management Studio work flawlessly?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, intellisense

I did see the answers and the steps suggested in [Why are my tables not showing up in SQL Server Management Studio's intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347386/why-is-are-my-tables-not-showing-up-in-sql-server-management-studios-intellisen)

But it seems buggy. Any real help other than just refresh cache?

Comment: I wish it worked the way it does in Visual studio. Even the VS 2003 was pretty darn good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No option but to post this as an answer.
Have a workaround for this.
You can install SQL Assistant.It works absolutely fine.

Comment: I'd love to, but there are constraints in installing third party software.